# Highcharts/highcharteR ignores point color when plotting 50+ series

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I've run into the problem where Highcharts/highcharteR seems to ignore individual point colours when plotting a certain number of series.

Reproducible example:

```
library(highcharter)

ll <- list()
for (i in 1:50) {
  ll[[i]] <- list(
              name = i,
              data = list_parse(
                        data.frame("x" = rep(i, 3),
                                   "y" = sample(1:10, 3, replace=TRUE),
                                   "z" = sample(1:5, 3, replace=TRUE),
                                   "color" = sample(c("green","red","grey"), 3))
                     )
              )
}
highchart() %>%
    hc_chart(type = "bubble") %>%
    hc_add_series_list(ll)
```

When running the above, you'll see random colours (assigned per series) instead of the explicitly specified green/red/grey colours. Changing the final line to `hc_add_series_list( ll[1:49] )` shows the correct, specified colours. I thought it was a problem with the final list item, but changing the final line to `hc_add_series_list( ll[2:50] )` also gives the correct result.

Generating a list with only 49 items (i.e., changing `for (i in 1:50)` to `for (i in 1:49)` does not have this problem (while generating a list with 51 items does). It seems that plotting 50 or more series is some sort of cut-off. Is this a highcharts/JS limitation?

Comment: You should report it on the Highcharter repo. This bug throws errors in gantt.js module (v 7.2.0). I was trying to debug it and I was able to get rid of errors, but the series are still not shown on the graph (with no errors in the console this time). There is nothing we (Highcharts support) can do. It works fine in pure JS: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/oyb5rehd/

Comment: Thanks so much @raf18seb! Found a solution on the repo while wanting to post this as a bug (see below; not sure whether it still counts as a bug though?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it is an issue with highcharteR's `boost`, which is enabled by default. Not sure what it does but thanks to [this GitHub comment](https://github.com/jbkunst/highcharter/issues/586#issuecomment-576343578), I found that adding `%>% hc_boost(enabled = FALSE)` solves the problem.

PS. Thanks to @raf18seb for testing whether this problem persists in pure JS (it doesn't).

Comment: Hmm, it's strange because the problem with boost was first that came to my mind. I was trying with boostThreshold and disabling boost and it didn't work for me. Maybe a typo or something :D glad you figured it out

Comment: That's strange indeed, for me it solved the problem. Do you know what this function does, is it specific to highcharteR or is it part of Highcharts?

Comment: Are you asking about boost? Boost is a part of Highcharts. It allows you to display hundreds of thousands of points without losing performance (of course many things are disabled, e.g. points' markers, dataLabels, different points colors etc.)

The boost automatically enables when you have many points or series - in your case 50 series. That is why you lost colors

Comment: Ah okay, makes sense thanks! Learning more and more about Highcharts and how it functions :)